# How to run JUnit 5 tests in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit5

I want to run JUnit test in Eclipse. I tried this:

I added POM dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

JUnit test

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class DatabaseFeaturesTest {

    @Test
    public void writeData() {
        System.out.println("Converting Map using bitmasking");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public void databaseInsert() {

    }
}
```

But when I run the test I get:

```
Aug 24, 2018 12:29:23 PM org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder buildRunner
WARNING: Ignoring test class using JUnitPlatform runner: org.rest.api.DatabaseFeaturesTest
Aug 24, 2018 12:29:23 PM org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder buildRunner
WARNING: Ignoring test class using JUnitPlatform runner: org.rest.api.DatabaseFeaturesTest
```

Can you give some advice where I'm wrong and how to fix the issue?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you running? According to [the docs](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/#junit-5-support) JUnit5 support was added in Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a).

Comment: I use Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

Comment: The answer from @johanneslink is correct: you do not need `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` to run JUnit 5 based tests in Eclipse 4.7.1a or higher. So, I'd recommend you accept his answer. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` which is JUnit 4‘s way to run Jupiter tests. With JUnit 5 platform support in Eclipse you no longer need it.